# ¿Cómo imprimir variables ya impresas pero repitiéndolas dentro de un modal?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código donde realizo un `while` para que me muestre los resultados de una consulta, y me muestra ya los valores.

Lo que yo quiero es que en un botón de "*ver más*", me muestre algunos de los datos ya impresos.

```html
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo "
<div>
  <table width='80%' border='0' align='center' class='thumbnail'>
    <tr align='center'>
      <td></td>
      <tr>
        <td width='50%'>
          <h4>".$row['nombre_e']."</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <td width='50%'>".$row['puesto_p']."</td>
      <td width='50%' align='right'>
        <img src=".$row['imagen']." width='60%' height='10%'>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    </td>
    <td width='50%'>".$row['carrerae_p']."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      </td>
      <td width='50%'>".$row['requisitos_p']."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      </td>
      <td width='50%'>".$row['descripcion_p']."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width='20%'>".$row['direccion_e']."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width='50%'>".$row['telefono_e']."</td>
      <tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='50%'>".$row['correo_e']." </td>
        </tr>
        <a href='#vermas' class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal'>ALUMNOS</a>
        <div class='modal fade' id='vermas'>
          <div class='modal-dialog '>
            <div class='modal-content'>
              <!------Header de la ventana ------>
              <div class='modal-header'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                <h4 class='modal-title'> Login Alumnos</h4>
              </div>
              <!------Contenido de la ventana--->
              <div class='modal-body'>
                <!----aqui contenido --->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br>"; } mysql_free_result($result) ?>
```

Comment: No entiendo.. ¿Qué te impide volver a imprimir la misma variable? Por ejemplo, usando de nuevo `$row['nombre_e']`

Comment: Uh... pero estás creando una tabla por cada registro que te devuelve la base de datos. ¿No crees que debieras tener una sola tabla e irle añadiendo filas acorde a los resultados? Aunque cada resultado genere dos o más filas, eso es anecdótico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como no tengo la data de tu query, ni la imagen de tus imágenes, ni el contexto de tus datos, me inventé un array llamado "cursos" con datos dummy.

Luego fui creando una tabla por cada curso y añadiéndola al div.

En cada tabla, la última fila tiene un botón que llama al modal. Pero además, al final de todo estoy declarando un listener que se encarga de rellenar el modal con el contenido de la tabla recién pinchada.

De las tablas visibles, cada una tiene dos elementos `tbody`. Lo hice de esta manera para que el modal no contuviese un nuevo botón para abrir un modal.

```js
// imagen en base64, un simple placeholder
var img_src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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";
// mi array de datos dummy
var cursos =[{
            nombre_e:'nombre1',
            imagen:img_src,
            correo_e:'correo_e1@gmail.com',
            datos: [
                'puesto_p1',
                'carrerae_p1',
                'requisitos_p1',
                'descripcion_p1',
                'direccion_e1',
                'telefono_e1',
               ]
          },  {
            nombre_e:'nombre2',
            imagen:img_src,
            correo_e:'correo_e2@gmail.com',
            datos: [
                'puesto_p2',
                'carrerae_p2',
                'requisitos_p2',
                'descripcion_p2',
                'direccion_e2',
                'telefono_e2'
              ]
         }];
  
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // Itero sobre cada curso para generar una tabla por c/u
    cursos.forEach(function(curso) {
      // genero la tabla y el primer tbody
      var theTable=jQuery("<table width='80%' border='1' align='center' class='thumbnail' id="+curso.nombre_e+">");
      var first_tbody=jQuery('<tbody>');
      
      // genero el primer tr, que es distinto al resto
      var first_tr=jQuery('<tr>');

      first_tr.append("<td width='50%'><h4>"+curso.nombre_e+"</h4></td>");
      first_tr.append("<td width='50%' align='right' rowspan='7'><img src="+curso.imagen+"  ></td>");
      first_tr.appendTo(first_tbody);
      // termino el primer tr y lo añado al primer tbody

      // los demás campos se tratan todos de la misma manera. 
      // los puse dentro de un sub-array para no escribirlos uno por uno
      curso.datos.forEach(function(dato) {
          var another_tr=jQuery('<tr>');
          another_tr.append("<td width='50%'>"+dato+"</td>");
          another_tr.appendTo(first_tbody);
      });
      first_tbody.appendTo(theTable);
      // termino el primer tbody y lo añado a la tabla

      // empiezo el segundo tbody que contendrá el botón abre-modal
      var segundo_tbody=jQuery('<tbody>');
      var last_tr=jQuery('<tr>');
      last_tr.append("<td width='50%'>"+curso.correo_e+"</td>");
      last_tr.append("<td><a href='#vermas' class='btnmodal btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal'>ALUMNOS</a></td>");
      last_tr.appendTo(segundo_tbody);
      segundo_tbody.appendTo(theTable);
      // termino el segundo tbody y lo añado a la tabla

      // añado la tabla al container principal
      theTable.appendTo('#container');

    });

    jQuery('.btnmodal').on('click',function() {
        var parentTable=jQuery(this).closest('table');
        jQuery('#modal_table')
                .find('tbody')
                .html(parentTable.find('tbody').first().html())
    });
    

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  
</div>
<br>
<div class='modal fade' id='vermas'>
          <div class='modal-dialog '>
            <div class='modal-content'>
              <!------Header de la ventana ------>
              <div class='modal-header'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                <h4 class='modal-title'> Login Alumnos</h4>
              </div>
              <!------Contenido de la ventana--->
              <div class='modal-body'>
               <table width='80%' border='1'class='thumbnail' id="modal_table">
               <tbody></tbody>
               </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió de mucho...!!!! 
excelente aporte

Answer (score 0):

Puede que tengas que volver a inicializar la consulta, cuando ejecutas un while recorres el array de la consulta y esta acaba.

Prueba con esto justo cuando acaba el while para reinicializar el array:

```
<?php mysql_data_seek($result, 0); ?>
```

Y copia el modal fuera del while, para ponerlo en otro while (y el data_seek en medio de estos dos).

Espero que te haya servido :)